# A question about definition of limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm  a beginner in Calculus.

In any text the definition of limit is stated as something like this

> **The function $f$ approaches the limit near $a$ means: for every $\epsilon >0$ there is some $\delta$ such that, for all $x$ if $0< |x-a| <\delta$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$.**

Here is my question.

Is it true that we can define the definition of limit in this way:

**" The function $f$ approaches the limit near $a$ means: for every $\delta >0$ there is some $\epsilon$ such that, for all $x$ if $0< |x-a| <\delta$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$"**

Intuitively, I would say the second definition still conveys  $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to the $l$ as $x$ moves closer and closer to $a$. Therefore I can't see the difference between the two. But  in any text I find, the authors always define limit as the firts one.

Comment: Your second definition is wrong. For instance, if it were correct, you could show that the constant null function $f:x\in\mathbb(R)\rightarrow f(x)=0$ has a limit of $1$ (or any value...) in $x=0$ just by taking, for any $\delta>0$, $\epsilon=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you want to define it, the function $f(x) = 1$ would have limit $0$ as $x\to 3$. We see this by showing that for any $\delta > 0$, we may choose $\epsilon = 2$ and this gives
$$
0<|x-3|<\delta\implies |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon
$$
for the simple reason that $|f(x) - 0| = 1$ no matter what $x$ is, and specifically for values of $x$ that are close to $3$.

For a more intuitive example of why "For any $x$ there is a $y$" is not equivalent to "For any $y$ there is a $x$", take the sentence "For any dog, there is a person such that that person owns that dog". If we swap it around, we get "For any person, there is a dog such that that person owns that dog". These two are clearly not equivalent statements (technically, since they are both false, they are equivalent, but it is very simple to think of a world or a society or a little vilage where one is true and the other is not, and in *that* sense they are not equivalent).